# Can we add text and video in adrotator?

Tags: adrotator

If we can add please give a small coding hint to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to this [`AdRotator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.adrotator.aspx) class, the short answer is no.

Comment: So how can i used to display video and text in it?

Comment: @jagdeep, code your own rotator. After all you are going to want to keep count of the number of clicks on each add etc., so building a custom component for this is probably your best option in any case.

Comment: @Hoffman: I accidently include video file instead of image in image url and the video is getting played over there.